# Selecting MAX number from MySQL table not working - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like below (a piece);

```
| Sl | NUMBER | Name |
----------------------
| 7  | 00007  | Name |
----------------------
| 8  | 00008  | Name |
----------------------
| 9  | 00009  | Name |
----------------------
| 10 | 00010  | Name |
----------------------
| 11 | 00011  | Name |
----------------------
| 12 | 00012  | Name |
----------------------
| 13 | 00013  | Name |
----------------------
```

and I have mysql statement like this;

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
if (!$con){
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);
$query = 'SELECT MAX(NUMBER) FROM tablename';//varchar 15 entry
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $maxnumber = $row['MAX(NUMBER)'];
}
echo $maxnumber;
```

But it returns 9 instead of 13. Why?

Comment: what is the `data type` of  column `NUMBER`? if it's varhar and not padded with zero, `9` is the maximum value.

Comment: It just works fine like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77f5c/1

Comment: If it actually returns `9` instead of `00009`, you seem to have data in the table that is not in your sample.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Well done - Good catch! +1 for that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM tablename AS t
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(SL) AS SL FROM tablename) AS r ON r.SL = t.SL
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77f5c/4)

Answer (score 6):

You indicate that the `column` data type is `varchar`. `MAX` works with numbers. You will need to cast it or change the `datatype`.

```
$query = 'SELECT MAX(CAST(NUMBER as UNSIGNED)) FROM tablename';
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `number` field doesn't appear to be a number data type, but a string data type instead. You must convert it to a number data type to get the right result. Try the code below:

```
$query = 'SELECT MAX(CAST(NUMBER as Int(12))) FROM tablename';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the query as follows

```
$query = 'SELECT NUMBER FROM tablename ORDER BY NUMBER DESC LIMIT 0,1';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(NUMBER AS UNSIGNED)) FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your number column not just number but zero-filled, try order descending and get the first one.

```
select number from tablename order by number desc limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$query = 'SELECT MAX(NUMBER) as NUMBER FROM test';//varchar 15 entry
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $maxnumber = $row['NUMBER'];
}
echo $maxnumber;
```

its return `00013`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like multiple reasons (although hard to explain). But I have 'cleaned' the code of some irregularities with some notes. Perhaps this is should work.

1: Assuming that the NAME field is VarChar, you had better convert it to numberic using the CAST functions. BUT this is NOT the problem.

2: You are reading all records and trying to print out of the loop. To start with, you do NOT need a loop. Since MAX is expected to return ONE record, a loop is redundant here.

3: When using a function like MAX, it's a good idea to take the resulting value into another variable. But this is NOT the problem. It's more like advice for 'cleaning' your code.

Now to the answer... The modified code should be like this:

```
$query = 'SELECT MAX(NUMBER) As M FROM tablename';//varchar 15 entry
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
$maxnumber = $row['M'];

echo $maxnumber;
```

This should do it :)

Answer (score 0):

the datatype of the NUMBER must be Integer or any numerical datatype, recheck it...
your query is correct.